# I want the sidepanel to show up AND be modified on one click, but it's requiring two clicks for Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome dictionary game extension, and the first part of the project requires a user to be able to right click on a word, and a sidepanel appears with definitions of the word (definitions found using a local database).
However, I am running into a small problem. A user has to right click on the word then press "define" *twice*, once to pull up the side panel THEN a second time to display the definition.
On the first click, it displays this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVHsD.png
And on the second click of "WordBank It!" it then displays the definition on the sidepanel:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8CFv.png
I want it to open the side panel *and* display the definition on one click, obviously for better ease of use. How can I do so? Here are my code files:

```js
// Copyright 2023 Google LLC
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.


function setupContextMenu() {
  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'define-word',
    title: 'WordBank It!',
    contexts: ['selection']
  });
}

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  setupContextMenu();
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  if (info.menuItemId === 'define-word') {
    // This will open the panel in all the pages on the current window.
    chrome.sidePanel.open({ windowId: tab.windowId });
    showDef(info.selectionText);
  }
  
});

function showDef(data) {
    // Hide instructions.
    document.body.querySelector('#select-a-word').style.display = 'none';

    // Show word and definition.
    document.body.querySelector('#definition-word').innerText = data.value;
    document.body.querySelector('#definition-text').innerText = words[data.value.toLowerCase()]; // websearch 
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dictionary Side Panel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Dictionary</h1>
    <hr />
    <p id="select-a-word">Select a word to see the definition.</p>
    <div>
      <h2 id="definition-word"></h2>
      <p id="definition-text"></p>
    </div>
    <script src="service-worker.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then obviously the manifest.json:

```js
{
  "name": "Dictionary side panel",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "description": "Provides definitions in the side panel.",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "tayy.png",
    "16": "tayy.png"
  },
  "side_panel": {
    "default_path": "sidepanel.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["sidePanel", "contextMenus"]
}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to split service-worker.js into two scripts because you have two different contexts. The service worker will register the menu and process the menu command, then open the side panel and send the selected text via messaging to its script. When the side panel is open it will listen to the menu directly.

##### service-worker.js:

Remove `function showDef` and move it into sidepanel.js

```js
let text;
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  if (info.menuItemId === 'define-word') {
    chrome.sidePanel.open({ windowId: tab.windowId });
    text = info.selectionText;
  }
});
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg === 'sidePanelInit') {
    sendResponse(text);
  }
});
```

##### sidepanel.html:

Load sidepanel.js instead of service-worker.js.

##### sidepanel.js:

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('sidePanelInit', showDef);
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((info, tab) => {
  if (info.menuItemId === 'define-word') {
    showDef(info.selectionText);
  }
});
function showDef(text) {
  document.querySelector('#definition-word').textContent = text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million. I was asking ChatGPT for help over and over running in circles and it gave me nothing. It works as intended now.